# Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am learning to code with this video https://youtu.be/1hPgQWbWmEk , I did exactly what the guy did, but when I run **expo start** and then go to **run in web browser** what appears is this error:

> Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with
> 'NavigationContainer'?

Here's my code until now

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {navigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'

import LandingScreen from './Components/auth/landing';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <navigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </navigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I know that if I erase this part the code doesn't show any errors

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
    <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

By the way, the code referred to in ./Components/auth/landing is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';


export default function Landing({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button 
            title="Register"
            onPress={() => navigator.navigate("Register")}/>
            <Button 
            title="Login"
            onPress={() => navigator.navigate("Login")}/>
            
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a typo in your code it must be `NavigationContainer` instead of `navigationContainer`.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would like to notice, that `NavigationContainer` is a necessary element for the stack navigator. It doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by wrapping my component with {} like so

```
return(
    <NavigationContainer>{ <Chat/> }</NavigationContainer>
);
```